# Looping through JSON data one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following test app: http://dev.driz.co.uk/quiztest/

The idea is that a series of webpages will each have a div that has the section number of quiz page e.g. 1 and then pull out the questions from a JSON file for that section.

This part I have working thanks to help from the SO community, so for clarity I have created a new question to deal with these issues which are separate.

The problem I have is that I only want the FIRST question to appear from a section on page load, and then when the user clicks on either the A or B button it then needs to load in the next question, so show question 2, and then 3 and so on...

**Only one question at a time will be in the `#questions` ul for the user to answer.**

Once all the questions for a section have been displayed I then need to do a callback to the finished function so that I can do some extra logic.

How do I best go about doing this? I'm thinking I'd need to first count the number of questions in the section and then do an increment to find the end. Can anyone help?

**Edit: I'm planning on doing something like: `Question 3 / 10` so getting that number is quite important it would seem. But I'm confused about getting the next question after the first and so and so on until then end of the section...**

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried implementing this at all, or are you stuck on the pseudo-code stage?

Comment: @Cameron stackoverflow users are writing your entire app.

Comment: @Cameron Well, I've posted an answer with a rough outline of how it should work. There's still a reasonable amount you'd need to implement yourself, and I don't know how accurately it fits what you currently have, but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: Your main issue is that your JSON structure sucks - I've updated the fiddle in my answer with the new structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have an array that contains your questions. Each question is an object, with a `question` key and an `answers` key. The `question` will always be a string that contains the text for the question. The `answers` will be an array with 0 or more elements of any type which signify the selectable answers to the question.

```
var questions = [
    {question : 'What is 2 + 2?', answers : [4, 5, 6]}, 
    {question : 'What is 6 * 4?', answers : [20, 24, 28]}
];
```

Now let's write a function to display a question. We'll use a global variable that stores the index of the question to be displayed (initialised to 0 to show the first question):

```
var currentQuestion = 0;

function displayQuestion() {
    if(currentQuestion < questions.length) { // if there's still questions to display
        var question = questions[currentQuestion]; // get the question to display
        var questionHtml = ...; // generate the HTML for the question here
        $('#questions').html(questionHtml);
        currentQuestion += 1; // increase tracking index
    }
    else {
        finished();
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is bind `click` event handlers to your buttons to call that `displayQuestion()` function.

Comment: @Cameron You wouldn't loop, you'd store the resulting object from your JSON and call this function a single time to display the first question, then subsequent times when an answer is selected to display the next question. I don't want to go in to too much detail, and purposely avoided looking at what you actually have already, because I think you'll learn more if you have to write most of the code for yourself.

Comment: This is what I have put together: http://pastebin.com/wEBYJeHU I take it I am doing this wrong? How would I get the data if I didn't loop through it?? At the moment I'm just getting the finished method straight away.

Comment: @Cameron The biggest issue is that your questions are currently stored in an object with keys starting at `"1"`, rather than being stored in a 0-indexed array. If you can I'd change the JSON because an array makes much more sense for this.

Comment: @Cameron Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/Q58rm/2/) jsFiddle. It simulates the `$.getJSON()` call, then basically replaces the response variable (`data`) with the JSON you'd actually get back on your page (so remove the `var data = ...` part). It does include the change to the JSON structure I mentioned, so that you're using an array rather than an object for your questions. It is possible to work with an object instead, but it makes less sense and is slightly more tricky to get the number of keys.

Answer (score 2):

I mocked what that website is in a fiddle. I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for. Maybe with more explanation I could get it closer. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEYHz/3/)

Comment: The functionality is perfect! But it should be pulling the questions out from the JSON and then counting the questions so that when it gets to the last question it just fires the finished method.

Comment: Where is the json? Can you include it in that fiddle?